# Custom similarity class solr not working

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I created as custom similarity class like this:

```
package org.apache.lucene.search.similarities;
import org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;

public class MyNewSimilarityClass extends DefaultSimilarity {

@Override
public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
public float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState arg0) {
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
public float tf(float freq) {
    return 1.0f;
}

}
```

Exported it to a jar file and uploaded it to my /dist folder inside solr.
In my solrconfig i added the following line:

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="similarityJar.*\.jar" />
```

In my schema.xml i added the following line:

```
<similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.MyNewSimilarityClass"> </similarity>
```

When is start my solr instance i can see that the jar is added to the class loader:

```
3170 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/var/www/apache-solr/dist/similarityJarNew.jar' to classloader
```

The server starts but gets stuck at:

```
3988 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – Reading Solr     Schema from /var/www/apache-solr/productie/solr/collection1/conf/sc                                hema.xml
4025 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – [collection1] Schema name=example
4174 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – user.dir=/var/www/apache-solr/productie
4174 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
4217 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  – Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

The core wont load after this.

When I comment out the line in my schema.xml that refers to the similarity class and start the server in the background everything goes fine and the core is loaded. Now when i uncomment the line in my schema.xml and reload the core in the admin panel everything still works but the new similarity class does not seem to work.

The scores and result order is still the same as before... 
Any help would be appreciated !!

I am using solr 4.10.2 on a CentOS server.

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell me about the right way to create this package. I'm kind of new to this. Here is mu question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144617/implementing-custom-solr-similarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was my java version on my local machine!

I was building the class with Java 1.8 the server version was 1.7. Reloading the schema.xml after uncommenting the line that points to the similarity class popped a error in the log that pointed out the problem.