# Implementing custom solr similarity

Tags: java, solr, lucene, similarity, scoring

Currently I need to implement custom solr similarity. So I found out that I need to override the DefaultSimilarity class in order to do this. Still I can't figure out how exactly it should be done and where to get source code which can be used for this purpose. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will need an answer:

What I needed to do was to create a package project in eclipse, download lucene-core jar and add it to the project. After that I imported the needed library and overrided the Similarity class.

After that I created a jar with the new similarity class. Added the jar to the solr/dist/ directory. Added a ref to the jar to the solrconfig file for the needed core. Used the similarity like any other similarity in the shema file.